# issue with cp_js_end not running on multiple extensions

Tags: control-panel, javascript, extension

I created 2 little extensions for EE 3.5.11 that use the hook cp_js_end and they add JavaScript to each page in the control panel.  The problem is that once one runs the other one does not, any idea what I need to do to prevent one from stopping the other one from running?

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to this link which solved my issue.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html#multiple-extensions-same-hook